# After installing mysqli phpmyadmin stop loading

Tags: mysql, php, phpmyadmin

On `Linux host 3.2.0-30-generic #48-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 24 16:52:48 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

phpmyadmin won't load after installing mysqlnd.

*I'm using php5, mysql AND mysqlnd. Maybe mysql and mysqlnd conflicts for phpmyadmin.*

- Problem:

  If I remove mysqlnd (mysqli support), PHP5 not working with mysqli, PHP5 only works with mysql. (Results for tests: `function_exists('mysqli_fetch_all') return FALSE`. That's ok.

  If I installed mysqlnd, php5-mysqlnd, PHP works with mysql + mysqli sumulately.
- Problems affected after mysqlnd install:

  After installing mysqli (mysqlnd) support, phpmyadmin won't load. Works PHP5 mysql + mysqlnd.

When installing once again phpmyadmin than **mysqlnd won't load**. PHP PDO and mysql only works.

Answer (score 0):

php5-mysqli has been replaced by php5-mysql

1. Install your php5 again using :

sudo apt-get install php5

1. Install php5-mysql using :

sudo apt-get install php5-mysql